# The prime power decomposition of sum of two squares

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, prime-factorization, sums-of-squares

> Show that if an integer is a sum of two squares: $n=x^2+y^2$, then in the prime power decomposition of $n$, all primes $p = 3 \pmod{4}$ appear with even exponents :
>
> For $p = 3 \pmod{4}$, if $p^k \mid n$ but $p^{k+1}$ doesn't then $k$ is even.

So I saw this - [Prime-power decomposition of a square](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/26384/prime-power-decomposition-of-a-square)

But it's quite different...

Any ideas?

Comment: @DietrichBurde Becuase how can I do the same?On the other post the talk about $n$ such that $n=m^2$,and here $n=x^2+y^2$,and therefore I can't simply look at the decomposition of one integer,but at the sum of them...

Comment: This is a quite elementary and well known fact in algebraic number theory.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $p \equiv 3 \pmod{4}$, with $p$ prime. You should know 
$$\tag{noroot}
\text{there is no $w$ such that $w^{2} \equiv -1 \pmod{p}$.}
$$ This is simply because if $p = 3 + 4 a$, the group of invertible elements modulo $p$ has order $$p - 1 = 2 (1 + 2 a) = 2 \cdot \text{odd number},$$ for some $a$, so it cannot have an element of order $4$ as $w$ would be.

Suppose by way of contradiction $$p^{2 k+1} \mid x^{2} + y^{2}, \quad\text{but}\quad p^{2 k+2} \nmid x^{2} + y^{2}.$$ We argue by induction on $k \ge 0$.

If $p \nmid x$, then $x$ has an inverse $z$ modulo $p$. Multiply $0 \equiv x^{2} + y^{2} \pmod{p}$ by $z$ to get
$$
-1 \equiv (z y)^{2} \pmod{p},
$$
a contradiction to (noroot).

Thus $p \mid x$, so that $p \mid y$ as well. If $k = 0$, this is a contradiction, because then $p^{2} \mid x^{2}, y^{2}$, so that $p^{2} \mid n$.

If $k > 0$, you get that
$$p^{2 k-1} \mid \left(\frac{x}{p}\right)^{2} + \left(\frac{y}{p}\right)^{2},$$ 
but 
$$p^{2 k} \nmid \left(\frac{x}{p}\right)^{2} + \left(\frac{y}{p}\right)^{2}.
$$ 
Induction now applies.

---

There is at least another proof, which involves Gaussian integers $G$. It is pretty easy to show that such a $p$ remains prime in $G$. Then if $p \mid x^{2} + y^{2} = (x + i y) (x - i y)$, it has to divide one of the factors, and thus both, as they are complex conjugates and $p$ is real. Now if $p^{e}$ is the largest power of $p$ dividing $x - i y$, then $p^{e}$ is also the largest power of $p$ dividing $x + i y$, so that $p^{2 e}$ is the largest power of $p$ dividing $x^{2} + y^{2}$.

Comment: Could you continue the induction?I don't understand what did you do after "If $k>0$ ,you get that...". And yrs,I'd love to see the other proof with Gaussian integers.

Comment: As to induction, that is simply the induction step, as you have fallen back to the $k-1$ case: $2 k - 1 = 2(k-1) + 1$ and $2 k = 2 (k-1) + 2$. I have written up the other proof.

Answer (score 3):

As pointed out by @Piquito, your problem is classically treated in any textbook on ANT. If you need to work it out, there is a concise answer using the Gaussian integers. The starting point is to decompose a rational prime $p$ in the ring   $A=\mathbf Z[i]$, which is a UFD. Result: $p$ splits in $A$ (i.e. $p$ is, up to $\pm 1, \pm i$ , a poduct of two distinct - necessarily complex conjugate - irreducible elements) iff $p$ is a sum of two squares, iff $p \equiv 1$ mod $4$. Consequence: given an integer $n$ written as a product of powers of distinct primes $p^{v_p (n)}$, $n$ is a sum of two squares iff, for all $p \equiv 3$ mod $4, {v_p (n)}$ is even.

Answer (score 0):

That's not true since there is no $x$ such that $x^2$ $=$ $-1$ $\pmod p$ if $p$ $=$ $3$ $\pmod 4$ or $d$ $|$ $p$ and $d$ $=$ $3$ $\pmod 4$. Factoring $x^2+y^2$ with real, or irrational numbers is impossible, you can factor it with imaginary numbers: $x^2+y^2$ $=$ $(x+iy)(x-iy)$, and $i^2$ $=$ $-1$.